# Can I use logistic analysis for two surveys that were conducted at two different time points

Tags: logistic, survey, group-differences

I have a two data sets - through two surveys that were conducted in the same organization at two different time points (couple of years apart). Both the surveys were to test if people experienced the event under investigation or not. So my outcome variable is yes or no for both the datasets. The other variables are age, gender and two categorical variables regarding type of job and nature of the contract. 
My question is can I use logistic regression to see if the odds of event occurring are significantly different between the two groups while controlling for the variables such as age, gender etc.?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the two samples contain the same people, partially the same people, or are they independent (meaning they contain completely different people)? If the samples are not independent, do you have a respondent ID that can match individuals between time periods?

Was the sampling process for each period standardized with no systematic differences between time period?

Comment: Actually I don't have any certainty about what percent of the people are same in both the groups since both the surveys were anonymous and have a participation rate of about 24%. I did chi square analysis of demographics between two samples and the age, gender and contract type are significantly different between the two. However in logistic regression only gender is significant predictor. The sampling process was  similar in the sense that emails with survey links were sent out to all staff members and the survey was voluntary and anonymous in both instances.

Comment: I don't have respondent ID to match individuals between two time periods. Thank you so much for your help. Greatly appreciate any suggestions you might have..

Comment: This isn't an uncommon issue in the surveying community. Things also partially come down to what is your question or hypothesis?  Obvious issues are related to knowing if there truly is an underlying difference between the groups or if you are just surveying two different groups of people. Also, if the two groups are not independent, you would want to control for the covariance between repeated response from the same individual.